# cache intermediate values on cluster

Tags: distributed, dask

I am running dask distributed and would like intermediate values to be saved. For example, when I run this:

```
from distributed import Client
client = Client(IP_PORT_TO_SCHEDULER)
from dask import delayed

@delayed(pure=True)
def myfunction(a):
    print("recomputing")
    return a + 3

res = myfunction(1)
res2 = res**2
res3 = client.persist(res2)

resagain = res**3
resagain2 = client.persist(resagain)
```

I would expect "recompute" to print only once. However, in this case it prints twice. I think this might be because the client doesn't cache this intermediate value. For example, running `client.has_what()`, I see this:

```
{'tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx': ['pow-9d66a68ce8be79ff9cca17a2dc58aa0b',
'pow-440784f1abedb14511aa0d633935b55a']}
```

I see the final result of the power functions but not the intermediate computation. Is there a way to force the client to store this intermediate computation? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask will hold on to all results that you have explicitly persisted.  Any intermediate results will be cleaned up in order to save on memory.

So in your case you probably want to do the following:

```
res = myfunction(1)
res = res.persist()  # Ask Dask to keep this in memory
...
```

Comment: thanks, I was trying to avoid this since now I have to add client dependent code in my libraries (and not just the running script). If a feature forcing the scheduler to save intermediate values is eventually supported, I'd be interested. (If there's interest, should we open an issue?)

Comment: I've edited my answer to show that you can use `dask.persist` or `res.persist()` rather than depend on the client.  On the single-machine schedulers this is the same as computing the result (persist will block) and returning a collection backed by those values.  This should allow you to write code that respects intermediates and works equally well on the single and distributed schedulers

Comment: thanks! (I read the docs after and this is perfect) It would be nice if something like this was posted as an example somewhere. I could write up a few lines of what we're using it for in case that may help?